# SQL Server to RedShift - invalid UTF8 error 3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift

I'm migrating data from MS PDW APS (SQL Server) using SSIS with an AWS toolkit. I have a column that is of type `varchar(max)` in the source and stores UNC path data.

Now certain records have what looks like GUID's in the path and some of these records conflict with the allowed UTF8 encoding. I was wondering what implicit conversions are allowed in Redshift? `varchar` to super? (PS I have redacted certain data with XXX's below but its all just text.)

ERROR:

> Amazon Redshift Destination [2]] Error: System.Exception: Exception: Exception: 22021: String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: be (error 3). Detail: . Line: 388, Position: 0, Source: varcharin / /home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/utils/adt/varchar.

DATA:

```
\\XXXXXXXXXXXX\FTP\USR\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\XX\BATCHARCHIVE-2020-12-11-00-07-50-85-B6205CA6-76BB-4172-86FE-AA5EAFEB0703.ZIP\436B4F16-A722-D0E6-8E44-02958B550001.OPUS.PGP
```

Comment: Since the character representations of GUIDs contain only ASCII characters I don't think they're the source of your problem. Have you exported the data into multiple UTF-8 encoded files and then tried to concatenate them into larger files? Perhaps you have a Byte Order Mark (U+FEFF Zero Width No-Break Space) or some other odd sequence at the beginning of line 388.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is correct but let me see if I can add some background.  Redshift expects characters to be encoded in the UTF-8 format which is most common outside of the Windows world which encodes in UTF-16.  SQL Server is a Microsoft product so it is likely that the data coming from SQL Server is UTF-16.  Here's a link for this conversion - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/9b68c357-a5b4-47bf-8efd-a05945210ca2/export-sql-view-to-flat-file-with-utf8-encoding?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Aside @BillWeiner... SQL Server defaults to UCS-2 string handling functions for nchar/nvarchar/ntext data types unless the database is using an _SC (Supplementary Characters) collation, at which point the string handling functions support UTF-16. While applications can store and read UTF-16 data in a non-SC database the string handling functions can give unexpected results when encountering it.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning.  Good to know.  I work w/ clients on ports to RS and character encodings is a common issue to work through.

Comment: @BillWeiner Aside from actually checking the database's collation settings there's a quick check you can even run from code... Using U+1F60A as as example (Smiling Face with Smiling Eyes) on a database with a supplementary characters collation (e.g.: Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC) `select nchar(128522)` will return a `` character but on a non-SC database it will return `null`.